# OpenSAML implementation to generate valid SOAP Header

Tags: java, saml-2.0, opensaml

I intend to create a SOAP Header through SAML token policy. I have written a method as follows:

```
        void addSamlTokenClientPolicy(SOAPMessageContext context){
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
        if (header == null) {
            header = envelope.addHeader();
        }

        SOAPFactory factory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPElement securityElem = factory.createElement(SoapSecurityHeaderConstants.SecurityEle,
        SoapSecurityHeaderConstants.prefix, SoapSecurityHeaderConstants.uri);

        String samlMetadataFile = "/samlMetadata.xml";

        // Initialize the library
        DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();

        // Get Parser Pool Manager
        BasicParserPool ppMgr = new BasicParserPool();
        ppMgr.setNamespaceAware(true);

        // Parse Metadata file
        InputStream in = CZSoapSecurityHandler.class.getResourceAsStream(samlMetadataFile);
        Document inDoc = ppMgr.parse(in);
        Element metadataRoot = inDoc.getDocumentElement();

        // Get appropriate unmarshaller
        UnmarshallerFactory unmarshallerFactory = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory();
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = unmarshallerFactory.getUnmarshaller(metadataRoot);

        XMLObject xmlObj = unmarshaller.unmarshall(metadataRoot);

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlObj.getDOM());
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        String strObject = result.getWriter().toString();

        securityElem.setTextContent(strObject);
        header.addChildElement(securityElem);
```

}

The content of the file `samlMetadata.xml` goes as:

```
        <saml:Assertion Version="2.0"
            ID="SAML-8z1f2F9fQ1EjegMIuH11Wg22" IssueInstant="2015-12-17T11:15:50Z"
            xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
            <saml:Issuer>xxx</saml:Issuer>
            <saml:Subject>
                <saml:NameID
                    Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">username</saml:NameID>
                <saml:SubjectConfirmation
                    Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:sender-vouches" />
            </saml:Subject>
            <saml:AuthnStatement
                AuthnInstant="2015-12-17T11:15:50Z">
                <saml:AuthnContext>
                    <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password
                    </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
                </saml:AuthnContext>
            </saml:AuthnStatement>
        </saml:Assertion>
```

The problem here is, it throws following error:

> Client received SOAP Fault from server: InvalidSecurity : error in processing the WS-Security security header.

I am quite certain the error is due to the code `securityElem.setTextContent(strObject)` where I am trying a workaround of setting text parsed from XML instead of adding child element. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.
The only thing missing in the code is the Marshaller. Added below lines in the code to populate the xmlObject into the SOAPEnvelope:

```
        XMLObject xmlObj = unmarshaller.unmarshall(metadataRoot);
        MarshallerFactory ms = Configuration.getMarshallerFactory();
        Marshaller mshaller = ms.getMarshaller(xmlObj);
        mshaller.marshall(xmlObj, securityElem);
        header.addChildElement(securityElem);
```